# Switching JSON response from custom to WP API V2

Tags: android, arrays, json, wordpress

I have a question about converting from a custom JSON response to WordPress standard JSON response for WP V2 API.

My custom json response looks like this - it's framed within

```
 {
  "categories":
  [26]
  0:
  {
    "term_id": 12
    "name": "Android"
    "slug": "android"
    "term_group": 0
    "term_taxonomy_id": 12
    "taxonomy": "category"
    "description": ""
    "parent": 463
    "count": 10
    "filter": "raw"
    "cat_ID": 12
    "category_count": 10
    "category_description": ""
    "cat_name": "Android"
    "category_nicename": "android"
    "category_parent": 463
   }
}
```

My code looks like this

```
    // Preparing volley's json object request
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

            try {
                if (response.has("error")) {
                    String error = response.getString("error");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    // Parsing the json response
                    JSONArray entry = response.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);

                    // loop through categories and add them to
                    // list
                    for (int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) entry.get(i);
                        // album id
                        String catID = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_ID);

                        // album title
                        String catTitle = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_NAME);

                        Category category = new Category();
                        category.setId(catID);
                        category.setTitle(catTitle);

                        // add album to list
                        categories.add(category);
                    }
```

The WordPress RST API V2 the JSON response looks like this:

```
[10]
 0:  {
    "id": 12
    "count": 10
    "description": ""
    "link": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/category/technology/mobile-apps/android/"
    "name": "Android"
    "slug": "android"
    "taxonomy": "category"
    "parent": 463
    "img": false
    "_links": {
       "self": [1]
        0:  {
          "href": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/12"
        }-
         - "collection": [1]
        0:  {
          "href": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"
        }-
        - "about": [1]
        0:  {
          "href": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/category"
        }-
        - "up": [1]
       0:  {
       "embeddable": true
         "href": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/463"
       }-
       -"wp:post_type": [1]
       0:  {
       "href": "https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=12"
       }-
       - "curies": [1]
       0:  {
        "name": "wp"
        "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}"
        "templated": true
       }
    }
  }
}
```

The new JSO response do not have a category called categories, so I can not use this statement.

```
     // Parsing the json response
      JSONArray entry = response.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);
```

I can not find any good documentation for the volley library or examples, my current code gets an object from the url, then the code uses the response.getJSONArray to get the array from the object.

What do I need to do if I can not identify the Array within the object, the json response I get is an array, should I change the request from object to array. I'm not sure a bit lost on this one. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an JsonObjectRequest, what was right for your api but now it comes an JsonArray from your api.

There is also a JsonArrayRequest in the Volley Toolbox. If you change the Request Type then it will work.

If something is not clear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the jsonObjectRequest with JsonArrayRequest and it's now working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my code snippet looks like after the change from JsonObjectRequest to  JsonArrayRequest
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject catObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    // album id
                    String catID = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_ID);

                    // album title
                    String catTitle = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_NAME);

                    Category category = new Category();
                    category.setId(catID);
                    category.setTitle(catTitle);

                    // add album to list
                    categories.add(category);

                    // Store categories in shared pref
                    AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger().storeCategories(categories);

                    // String the main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
```